# C# code to add child nodes to tree view control without looping

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a code to dynamically create a tree and child nodes but adding of child nodes takes long time since the code loops through across each item and then creates a child tree node, is there any way of adding all child nodes in one go?

```
            TreeNode TreeNodeDatabase = new TreeNode();
            TreeNodeDatabase.Text = "Database";
            TreeNodeDatabase.Value = "Database";
            TreeNodeDatabase.Expanded = false;
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(TreeNodeDatabase);

            //Table
            TreeNode TreeNodeTables = new TreeNode();
            TreeNodeTables.Text = "Table";
            TreeNodeTables.Value = "Table";
            TreeNodeTables.Expanded = false;
            TreeNodeDatabase.ChildNodes.Add(TreeNodeTables);

            //Now Add Child Nodes to Table
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            HandleDB db = new HandleDB();
            ds = db.returnData("select top 1 name from sys.tables", srvr, dbname);             

            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TreeNode TreeNodeTableName = new TreeNode();

                TreeNodeTableName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                TreeNodeTableName.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                TreeNodeTableName.Expanded = false;
                TreeNodeTables.ChildNodes.Add(TreeNodeTableName);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a reason to load the entire tree-view during the initial load then you should load it **on demand**.

The easiest way to do this is to:

1. Load all nodes based on a logical level (Root Node + All Children).
2. Store the identifier and node type with each node. (You can append a pointer to an object that describes each node and identifying information).
3. Create a function that will load a nodes direct decedents(You will need one at every node level that is not an organizational level node).
4. For each node, when clicked, determine if it has children and if not load the child nodes and apply meta data (It would be better here to have a property on your meta-data object like *HasBeenLoaded* so you don't make repeated child load calls for nodes with no children when clicked).

Answer (score 0):

The TreeView has a Nodes TreeNodeCollection.  You could so something like this.

TreeView1.Nodes.AddRange([yourtreenodecollection])

You'd still have to do some looping by building a new TreeNodeCollection, but this would provide much better performance than manually adding each TreeNode to the Tree.  There doesn't seem to be an explicit way to bind the TreeView to a database.